# JAXB binding: dynamic class names for repeated elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have an XSD with repeated elements of name `row` that are generating collisions when trying to parse it with XJC. I would like to know if there's a way to append an index to each name so as to generate unique class names, such as `Row1.java`, `Row2.java`, `Row3.java` and so on.

**sample.xsd**

```
    <xsd:complexType name="table">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>                   
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>          
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

**binding.xml**

```
    <jxb:bindings version="2.1"
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="sample.xsd">
            <jxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel" />
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='row']" multiple="true" >
                <jxb:class name="RowXX"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

**xjc command**

```
    xjc -extension binding.xml sample.xsd
```

I tried using XPath expressions but I get rubbish output like `_002f_002fXsElement_005b1_005d.java`. Maybe the approach I'm taking is wrong. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want a single Table.Row but multiple Row classes with  a suffix (e.g. an index) in other to differentiate the repeated elements. I'm not sure if this is even possible with XJC.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the schema you have.  You say `row` can be repeated an infinite number of time (given physical limits).  How many classes should xjc generate?  If the classes you describe are really what you want, then the schema you want is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="table">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="row1" minOccurs="0">
         <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
         </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="row2" minOccurs="0">
         <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
         </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="row3" minOccurs="0">
         <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
         </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      ...
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Actually, it is something much more complex, to ensure that `row{n+1}` appears only when `row{n}` is present, but you get the idea.

My feeling is: you have another problem you are trying to solve, and you decided that having such *numbered* classes is the solution to that (those) problem(s).  If you identify why you want such classes in the first place, we might find a better solution.